# How to get rid of special characters but still keep spaces in formatting a string?

Tags: vb.net

I have a form which includes a textbox for a last name of which I am formatting. And I am trying to get rid of special such as '-' ,'+', etc. But I want the user to still be able to put in space in between just incase the person they are entering is a last name with Jr or Sr at the end. So far I have

```
    txt.Text = Regex.Replace(txt.Text, "\W|\d", "")
```

but this gets rid of spaces as well. How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Note that some last names have an apostrophe, e.g. O'Toole, and some have hyphens, such as Zeta-Jones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of regex you could use this (more efficient) approach:

```
Dim characters = txt.Text.ToCharArray()
characters = Array.FindAll(characters, Function(c) Char.IsLetter(c) OrElse c = " "c)
txt.Text = new string(characters)
```

Comment: Comment on the edit. Although tagged VB sometimes when doing a search you find yourself on a question which is not your preferred language and having both helps in my opinion.